# Highcarts in Laravel

Tags: laravel, highcharts

I'm trying to render a chart in a Laravel view, i built the chart in the controller but it doesn't work unless i disable the js/app.js, can someone tell me why?

Controller:

```
$chart1 = \Chart::title([
            'text' => 'Voting',
        ])
        ->chart([
            'type'     => 'line', // pie , columnt ect
            'renderTo' => 'chart1', // render the chart into your div with id
        ])
        ->subtitle([
            'text' => 'This Subtitle',
        ])
        ->colors([
            '#0c2959'
        ])
        ->xaxis([
            'categories' => [
                'data 1',
                'data 2',
                'data 3',
                'data 4',
            ],
            'labels'     => [
                'rotation'  => 15,
                'align'     => 'top',
                'formatter' => 'startJs:function(){return this.value + " (Player)"}:endJs', 
                // use 'startJs:yourjavasscripthere:endJs'
            ],
        ])
        ->yaxis([
            'text' => 'This Y Axis',
        ])
        ->legend([
            'layout'        => 'vertikal',
            'align'         => 'right',
            'verticalAlign' => 'middle',
        ])
        ->series(
            [
                [
                    'name'  => 'Voting',
                    'data'  => [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658],
                    // 'color' => '#0c2959',
                ],
            ]
        )
        ->display();
    
        return view('devices.show', compact('readings', 'chart1'));
```

Laravel View:

```
        <div id="chart1"></div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! $chart1 !!}
</body>
</html>
```

The {!! $chart1 !!} is outside of the id=app div

Comment: Highcharts doesn't have an official version of the wrapper for Laravel, so I am afraid I am not able to help you. You can try to contact the Highcharts Laravel wrapper creator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you suggest me what charts framework work fine with Laravel 7 or 8? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i installed Laravel with VUE.js, and VUE was creating the div `<div id="app">`, and you can't run any JavaScript inside that DIV, i disabled VUE.js and the chart worked